# Unauthenticated user in Artfactory after migrating to SBT 0.13.5

Tags: sbt, artifactory

I do have a team of 7 members, set up behind a proxy, and we moved from sbt 0.13.1 to 0.13.5.
After the sbt migration, one of the team members can't execute sbt anymore.
All my dependencies are set up in the artifactory, and I don't have access to external repositories.
SBT repositories are been overwritten using a system variable.

I've put 'repositories' file into ~/.sbt/
'repositories' file includes:

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repoaddress/artifactory/Ivy-remote/,[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

I've included '-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true' in SBT's launch command using a system variable.

Whenever he tries to load sbt, it fail due to the unresolved dependency SBT 0.13.5
I want to know if there is a way to log the http responses from the tries to find sbt 0.13.5?

Artifactory request.log shows that this specific user is:
`non_authenticated_user`

Credentials to my artifactory was added in the credentials.sbt file located inside sbt_home/plugins/
And the credentials file was added to the .ivy2/.credentials file.
I've already changed the user to an admin user that works in another workstation but I still can't get the sbt 0.13.5.
The error log is showed above:

```
    HTTP response status: 401 url=http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.pom
    my-maven-proxy-releases: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#logging;0.13.5: res=http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.pom
     trying http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.jar
        tried http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.jar
try to get credentials for: Artifactory Realm@repositorio.ginfes.intranet.local
authentication: k='Artifactory Realm@repositorio.ginfes.intranet.local' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=http://repoaddress/artifactory/remote-repos/org/scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/logging-0.13.5.jar
```

This log message is resumed, to avoid scrolling.
I've already tried to run using the jave http.proxy arguments, as showed in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/PqpiSjnaa2s)
and I've added the repositories as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583665/getting-both-maven-and-sbt-use-local-artifactory-server) but the same error still happening.
This problem doesn't happen when my project was configured with sbt 0.13.1.
This error happens when I execute the project using sbt versions 0.13.1 and 0.13.5

Is there a way to fixing this authentication problem? Am I missing an artifactory configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config files is now versioned in 0.13.5, just moved my repository config files from the

```
~/./sbt/
```

to

```
~/.sbt/0.13/
```

folder

Comment: I don't think `repositories` is versioned.

Comment: By versioned I mean that it was located under the folder .sbt/sbt_version