# Sbt and maven using local artifactory server

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, artifactory, dependency-resolution

Similar to [Getting both Maven and SBT use local Artifactory-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583665/getting-both-maven-and-sbt-use-local-artifactory-server) I want to get sbt and maven to use the local artifactory server. For SBT I am facing some problems:

```
(o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:766) - IO error while trying to download resource 'repo1:net/virtual-void/sbt-dependency-graph_2.10_0.13/0.8.2/sbt-dependency-graph-0.8.2.pom': org.artifactory.api.repo.exception.maven.BadPomException: The target deployment path 'net/virtual-void/sbt-dependency-graph_2.10_0.13/0.8.2/sbt-dependency-graph-0.8.2.pom' does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'net/virtual-void/sbt-dependency-graph/0.8.2'. Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path
```

Adding https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ as an ivy or maven project did not help.

Sbt has the following settings

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://url/artifactory/virtual-dev/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://url/artifactory/virtual-dev/
  my-maven-proxy-snapshots: http://url/artifactory/virtual-dev/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Suppress POM Consistency Checks" checkbox on the configuration page for the remote repository "repo1". Check it, and artifactory will ignore POM inconsistencies.